# Why doesn't Minato use Sage mode against the "Masked Man"?

Tags: naruto

We all know that Minato was able to use sage mode, but when the nine-tails attacked the hidden leaf, why didn't Minato go into sage mode and destroy the "Masked Man"

Comment: Sage mode requires you to be still and absorb nature energy. In the time of crisis, Minato didn't have the time to sit still and enter sage mode

Comment: I know, but he had time, because of his flying thunder god. However, in Naruto's case, he couldn't use the flying thunder god, so he wouldn't have time. In Minato's case, he could've just entered sage mode and then teleported. The flying thunder god technique makes up for the time that is needed for sage mode.

Comment: Your argument is not clear. How do you say that Minato had time to enter sage mode? Cuz teleporting makes you move which avoids you from entering into sage mode.

Comment: First of all Naruto uses clones to absorb the energy for him and because Minato is restricted to only one or two clones it is not an effective strategy to divide your chakra and lose the ability to use all your power when you need to. Second, I think Minato was not as good as Naruto and Giraya in controlling the natural energy. And lastly the flying thunder does not make up for the lost time, while Minato is sitting still to absorb the natural energy the enemy could cause too much damage. he could teleport from one place to another not from one TIME to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 4th great ninja war Minato himself says that he can't use sage mode efficiently. This because it requires a lot of time to gather that much chakra, and he is not adept at using sage mode. [image]

Answer (score -3):

***Kishimoto didn't think of it lol, plus if he had used sage mode we wouldn't have the great story we have today so i rather have this great story with some plot holes. just like on star wars why didn't obiwan use force run to save qui gon instead of running normally when he had clearly used it at the beginning of the movie to get away from the droidekas.***

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. As it stands, it is more of an opinion or an assumption without anything to back it up.